# Can't create a unique url for Mobile Service at Azure

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, unique-key, azure-management

I was having trouble to create a unique url at windows azure for a new Mobile Service.

The url is always "unique-name".azure-mobile.net.

So, I made a simple test. Generate a random word-number string of 45 characters.

That is the result:
[image]

After that, I was sure that this is a bug and this is not my lack of creativity in url names.

Anyone knows any around for that?

Answer (score 2):

They deprecated the creation of Mobile Service at Manage Portal.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2016/05/20/azure-mobile-service-creation-fails-this-name-is-already-in-use/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transition-of-azure-mobile-services/

End of line... now we have to get use to the horrible new portal! :s

Comment: That's right. The error message is confusing (we're fixing it), but the actual error is that you can't create a Mobile Service. 

Btw, you can provide feedback on the new portal by using the smiley-face icon on the top right. Be specific about what you don't like, so that it can be improved.